# Incompatible jaxb dependencies

Tags: java, jaxb

This goes back to one of my [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139996/proper-way-to-use-spring-jaxb-marshaller-with-java-9-without-defining-additional).
I basically followed [this tutorial](https://springframework.guru/using-jaxb-for-xml-with-java/) for JAXB. Therefore I ended up with this simplified model class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * @author Andi Hotz, (c) Sahits GmbH, 2018
 * Created on Nov 06, 2018
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String productId;
    @XmlElement(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @XmlElement(name = "imageUrl")
    private String imageUrl;
    @XmlElement(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    public Product(){}
    public Product(String productId, String description, String imageUrl,
                   BigDecimal price) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "\n productId='" + productId + '\'' +
                ",\n description='" + description + '\'' +
                ",\n imageUrl='" + imageUrl + '\'' +
                ",\n price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And the corresponding test, that causes the exception (see further down):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * @author Andi Hotz, (c) Sahits GmbH, 2018
 * Created on Nov 06, 2018
 */
class ProductToXmlTest {
    private Product product;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        long l = 10;
        Long longId = new Long(l);
        User user = new User(longId, "John", "john@springframework.guru");
        product = new Product("PO1", "Spring Guru Mug",
                "https://springframework.guru/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/spring_framework_guru_shirt-rf412049699c14ba5b68bb1c09182bfa2_8nax2_512.jpg",
                new BigDecimal(18.95));
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        product = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testObjectToXml() throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(product, new File("product.xml"));
        marshaller.marshal(product, System.out);
    }
}
```

The Maven pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ch.sahits.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Running the test (from within IntelliJ) produces this exception:
/

```
usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dvisualvm.id=4023804890528 -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU-182.4892.20/lib/idea_rt.jar=34101:/opt/idea-IU-182.4892.20/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/idea-IU-182.4892.20/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/idea-IU-182.4892.20/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/opt/idea-IU-182.4892.20/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/home/andi/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-launcher/1.2.0/junit-platform-launcher-1.2.0.jar:/home/andi/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.0.0/apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar:/home/andi/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.2.0/junit-platform-engine-1.2.0.jar:/home/andi/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.2.0/junit-platform-commons-1.2.0.jar:/home/andi/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.1.0/opentest4j-1.1.0.jar:/home/andi/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.2.0/junit-jupiter-engine-5.2.0.jar:/home/andi/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.2.0/junit-jupiter-api-5.2.0.jar:/home/andi/development/intellij/spring-jaxb/target/test-classes:/home/andi/development/intellij/spring-jaxb/target/classes:/home/andi/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/home/andi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.0/jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 ch.sahits.test.model.ProductToXmlTest

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3294)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2107)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:295)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at ch.sahits.test.model.ProductToXmlTest.testObjectToXml(ProductToXmlTest.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:113)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 74 more
```

The exception suggests that I am missing some dependency since the `AnnotationReader` is the base interface of `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeAnnotationReader` which is part of the jaxb-runtime, but obviously not on the classpath.

I could also imagine that the javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api is not fully compatible with org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime.

How to setup the dependencies to make them work with this example?

Comment: Try using version 2.3.1 instead of 2.3.0. I have a [blog post](https://www.jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/) with more details.

Comment: @Jesper Nice, do you have any idea why it works with 2.3.1 but not 2.3.0?

Comment: When I was researching for my blog post, I remember getting similar problems (although I'm not sure it was exactly same same as the problem you found); submitted a support ticket to the project and someone suggested me to use the latest version.