# Java 11 package javax.xml.soap does not exist

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, java-11

I'm trying to create a simple message using [SOAP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/package-summary.html):

```java
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage();
```

When I build the project with **Java 8** it's fine, but building it with **Java 11** fails with a compilation error:

```
package javax.xml.soap does not exist
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

## JAX-WS removed from Java 11

[JAX-WS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services) is no longer bundled with Java 11.

According to the [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8190378), Java 11 removed the Java EE modules:

```
java.xml.ws (JAX-WS, plus the related technologies SAAJ and Web Services Metadata) - REMOVED
```

- Java 8 - OK
- Java 9 - DEPRECATED
- Java 10 - DEPRECATED
- Java 11 - REMOVED

See [JEP 320](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320#Java-EE-modules) for more info.

You can fix the issue by using alternate versions of the Java EE technologies. Simply add a [com.sun.xml.ws : jaxws-ri](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-ri) Maven artifact that contains the technologies you need:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

### Jakarta EE 8 update (Mar 2020)

Instead of using old JAX-WS module you can fix the issue by using [Jakarta XML Web Services](https://search.maven.org/artifact/jakarta.xml.ws/jakarta.xml.ws-api) from [Jakarta EE 8](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-web-services/2.3/):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

### Jakarta EE 9 update (Nov 2020)

Use latest release of Jakarta XML Web Services [3.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-web-services/3.0/):

- Jakarta EE9 API [jakarta.xml.ws-api](https://search.maven.org/artifact/jakarta.xml.ws/jakarta.xml.ws-api)
- compatible implementation [jaxws-rt](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** change `javax.*` imports to `jakarta.*`

### Jakarta EE 10 update (Jun 2022)

Use latest release of Jakarta XML Web Services [4.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-web-services/4.0/) (requires Java SE 11 or newer):

- Jakarta EE 10 API [jakarta.xml.ws-api](https://search.maven.org/artifact/jakarta.xml.ws/jakarta.xml.ws-api)
- compatible implementation [jaxws-rt](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Be aware, the above `jaxws-ri` dependency includes a lot of jar files, you probably don't need all of them.

Comment: Hi, I´ve tried your approach but there are some missing (or wrong) dependencies - I´ve asked on my own question, without answer so far. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395722/migrating-from-java-8-to-11-jaxws-rt

Comment: @holmis83, I have updated the answer with Jakarta EE 8, which is free of the issue you pointed out.

Comment: @holmis83 - I just upgraded my old school JDK 7 app => JDK 11 using the jakarta dependency. Thank you!  Saved me a lot of hair pulling!

Comment: I run Redhat OpenJDK 8 for windows and javax.xml packages are gone.

Comment: @LeosLiterak can you provide a link to the JDK?

Comment: I was wrong. Upgraded Idea used the bundled JDK 11.